# Necessary relation for closed lines on minimal surfaces

Tags: minimal-surfaces

Is there a necessary relation between curvature and torsion of a closed non-intersecting curve on a minimal surface?

While playing with soap films I noted  closed light threads migrating on a soap film in a certain way difficult to mathematically describe. I cannot imagine the motion is  arbitrary. This can be also seen on solid surfaces catenoid surfaces if a string lying on it is displaced by hand.

EDIT1:

It may be in some way related to the Plateau / Rado problems.

Comment: this is good http://store.doverpublications.com/0486205428.html  There is a later book by Cyril Isenberg with some color photographs, they don't seem to carry it anymore  http://www.amazon.com/The-Science-Soap-Films-Bubbles/dp/0486269604

Comment: Thanks, shall access Boys; am familiar with the second book,actually a favorite.

Comment: Evidently a number of later books I have not seen before, listed on the amazon page as suggestions